# how to force terminate aws instances which are stuck in Waiting for Launch Lifecycle Action state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, autoscaling

I would like to know how to force terminate aws instances which are stuck in Waiting for Launch Lifecycle Action state.

Because my instances are getting abandoned in this state, I'm not able to  achieve additional auto scaling in or out.

When I try

```
 aws autoscaling terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group --instance-id $i --should-decrement-desired-capacity
```

I'm met with

```
An error occurred (ScalingActivityInProgress) when calling the TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup operation: Activity 87a5b65f-3f73-64da-f2d7-0721543f3cff is in progress.
aws autoscaling terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group --instance-id i-abcd --should-decrement-desired-capacity
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of terminating the instance complete the lifecycle action with a result of ABANDON. For example,

```sh
$ aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action \
  --lifecycle-hook-name YOUR_HOOK_NAME \
  --auto-scaling-group-name YOUR_GROUP_NAME \
  --lifecycle-action-result ABANDON \
  --instance-id YOUR_INSTANCE_ID
```